# How to include simple-json in grails war builds

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have the following in my buildConfig:

```
compile ":json-rest-api:1.0.11"
```

When I look at dependencies under my classpath via Eclipse STS I can see *simple-json-1.1.jar* is included.

When I build a war for deployment I see that it does not include this jar.
I need it in deployments to test push notifications. I am getting the current error at the moment because the class is missing:

```
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85) org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:97)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,390 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:490)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at com.mysite.notification.AndroidNotificationService.class$(AndroidNotificationService.groovy)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at com.mysite.notification.AndroidNotificationService.$get$$class$com$google$android$gcm$server$Sender(AndroidNotificationService.groovy)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,391 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at com.mysite.notification.AndroidNotificationService.sendMessage(AndroidNotificationService.groovy:22)
2013-02-11 08:55:46,393 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-85)      at com.mysite.notification.AndroidNotificationService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$5e8e3148.invoke(<generated>)
```

Do I need to explicity set this somewhere? Does it even a dependency of the json-rest-api plugin?

Thanks

Comment: I'd use `grails dependency-report` to work out where it's coming from.  It doesn't appear to be a dependency of `json-rest-api`.  If it turns out to be a transitive dependency of something that's in `build` scope then it won't get into the war, you'll have to add an explicit `runtime` dependency for that.

Comment: Ok. It appears to be json-simple by com.googlecode.json-simple. I currenly have the following in buildConfig also:
dependencies {
  compile'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'
  compile 'com.google.gcm:gcm:1.0'
  compile 'com.google.gcm:gcm-server:1.0'
}
Maybe I need to added?
compile 'org.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after using grails dependency-report as suggested by Ian, I discovered it was coming from [com.googlecode.json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

I added the folllwing to my buildConfig.groovy and it get pulled in correctly when building:

```
dependencies {      
        compile 'org.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: ya, i had to add the com.googlecode.json-simple as well:    `repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    }`

Comment: I also had to do as @Tak suggests.